# KIVY DragBehavior Custom Widget

Tags: kivy, drag, android-relativelayout

I am trying to use DragBehavior to help in moving my custom widget across RelativeLayout. Find below sample code. Why my widget is not moving on Drag action please. For simplicity I had included only rectangle in my custom widget MyPaintWidget

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

Builder.load_string("""
<MyPaintWidget>:
    # Define the properties for the DragLabel
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
""")


class MyPaintWidget(DragBehavior, Scatter):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) :
        self.selected = None
        self.touched = False
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def create_figure(self,  **kwargs):
        print ('position is {}'.format(self.pos))
        print ('width Height {}'.format(self.to_parent(self.width, self.height)))
        self.canvas.add(Rectangle(pos  = self.pos, size = self.size))
        return self

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print('Started to move x: {} y: {}'.format(touch.x, touch.y))
        return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_move(touch)


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = RelativeLayout()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget(pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, 'center_y':0.5}, size_hint=(.2,.1))

        parent.add_widget(self.painter.create_figure())
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DragBehavior` works by adjusting the `pos` of your `MyPaintWidget`, but you have set `pos_hint` on the `MyPaintWidget`. The `pos_hint` takes precedence over `pos`, so while the drag changes `pos`, it is ignored because there is a `pos_hint`. Also, the `Rectangle` that you draw in `create_figure` has its `size` and `pos` set when that method is called, and there is no mechanism to change it when the `MyPaintWidget` is moved. So, even if the `Widget` was being dragged, the `Rectangle` would not move.

Here is a version of your code with those problems corrected:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<MyPaintWidget>:
    # Define the properties for the DragLabel
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0,0  # only do this for RelativeLayout
            size: self.size
""")


class MyPaintWidget(DragBehavior, Scatter):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) :
        self.selected = None
        self.touched = False
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print('Started to move x: {} y: {}'.format(touch.x, touch.y))
        return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_move(touch)


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = RelativeLayout()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget( pos=(240, 200), size_hint=(.2,.1))

        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For positioning MyPaintWidget I used pos_hint because if I change my parent layout (Relativelayout) size, I want my widget to resize and reposition accordingly. For example I want my widget to be in the middle of the Relative layout irrespective of layout size. So pos_hint was used. With using pos, I need to write my custom code to move the widgets on Relativelayou size changes. Is my understanding right.

Comment: You got it. The `pos_hint` is a convenience, and you can implement the same thing using binding.